# A set of results in Decision Tree

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, decision-tree

I have a data which is 1672x6. I have put some of them in the picture.

[image]
where x values are A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 A6 and y values are B1 B2 ....B1672.

I used the following code while generating decision trees:

```
vars = {'A1', ' A2 ','A3',' A4 ','A5',' A6'}
x = [A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 A6];
y = [B];
t = classregtree(x, y, 'method','classification', 'names',vars, ...
                 'categorical',[2 4], 'prune','off');
view(t)
```

and it generates super crazy trees like

[image]

I want to get the values which are greater than the values that I gave. When I say :

```
inst = [3 2.3 2 0 1 0];
prediction = eval(t, inst)
```

It only gives me the B value (like B271) which has that variable but I want to get all B variables which have greater values than `inst` variable such as  `A1>3 A2>2.3 A3>2 A4>0 A5>1 A6>0`. How can I get them?

Comment: Why do you need decision tree? It seems you only want to get all the rows that are greater than `inst`. Or do you need to use decision tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to confuse two things: *decision tree* and *finding desired rows*

If you want to find all the rows that are greater than `inst`, the following is a simple code that prints all such rows.

```
for i = 1:size(B,1)
    if  all(a(i,:)>inst)==1 
        i, 
    end
end
```

However, *decision tree* is a totally different topic. In a *decision tree*, you have a set of conditions (A1 to A6 in your case) and many rows for training (B1 to B1672) and a consequence for each one of them. When a new test case is queried, the machine decides on best possible consequence out of all the consequences.

Some decision tree totorials: [1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-dCtJjlEEgM&list=PLTsfgBpyh5EqvE5Va9HkPcy64ktAL38PG&index=2), [2](https://www.mindtools.com/dectree.html) and [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree)